# How to explode a vector and use its values as the arguments of a function?

Tags: c++, oracle, boost, vector

What I am currently doing is:

```
std::vector<sometype> myparams;
...
while (...)
  myparams.push_back(somevalue);
...

somefunction(myparams[0], myparams[1], myparams[2], otherargument);
```

I have many implementation of somefunction accepting 1 to 100 arguments.
I cannot change somefunction however I would like to know if there is a prettier way to use it and thus whatever the size of myparams by creating another function/macro which would accept a vector as argument and call somefunction with all the the value of the vector as arguments.

any idea ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear; you'd like to be able to call a particular function overload based on the dynamic size of the vector?

Comment: Hate to prod but why can't you change somefunc?  C++ is the language to use if you're trying to fight one bad programming practice with another but I'd be surprised if somefunc really is written in stone.  And if you've implemented it 100 times, how bad can the 101st be that accepts a vector as argument?

Comment: I'm guessing you are coming from some other programming language (like PHP) where this is included in some form in the language. I'd say you have to rethink your design and in the function process the vector.

Comment: @djechlin I'm guessing this is related to SQL parameter binding. Dante, can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, somefunction binds the arguments to the 'where' parameters of an oracle select.

Comment: C++ to SQL is not my domain but this is bad design and there's a better way to do it entirely, possibly by rethinking the use of SQL or the DB library.

Comment: @djechlin This is a fundamental limitation of how SQL bind parameters work in every DBMS I know of. When you construct your SQL text, it has to have the _exact_ number of bind parameters. You can always construct a different SQL text dynamically, but you are then missing the performance benefits of prepared statements (and possibly security - depends on how you do it). That being said, stored procedures usually can accept types such as "table" or "array" or "XML", which effectively sidesteps this limitation, but I'm guessing OP's code generator is limited there.

Comment: Ok but possibly a design issue in the DB.  I wonder if the 1-to-100 parameters that can be input are really homogeneous elements of one table.  Or if this should be accomplished by a while() loop around somefunc() incrementing the index each time.  And in what database does it make sense to let you change 1 to 100 parameters at a time but not arbitary numbers?  That's why I think the OP is still asking the wrong question.

Comment: You can easily have that situation for `WHERE field IN (list_of_values)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't really be doing that, but here you go :) Using the boost::preprocessor:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>

void somefunction(int p1)
    { std::cout << p1 << " " << std::endl;}
void somefunction(int p1, int p2) 
    { std::cout << p1 << " " << p2 << std::endl;}
void somefunction(int p1, int p2, int p3) 
    { std::cout << p1 << " " << p2 << " " << p3 << std::endl;}
void somefunction(int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4)
    { std::cout << p1 << " " << p2 << " " << p3 << " " << p4 << std::endl;}

#define MAX_ARGS 4

#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition.hpp>

void UnpackVector(const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    #define MACRO(z, n, _) \
    case n: somefunction(\
    BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS(BOOST_PP_INC(n), v[,]BOOST_PP_INTERCEPT) \
    );break;

    switch(v.size() - 1)
    {
        BOOST_PP_REPEAT(MAX_ARGS, MACRO, nil)
    }
}

void Run()
{
    int v_[] = { 42, 41, 40, 39 };
    std::vector<int> v(v_, v_ + sizeof(v_) / sizeof(int));

    UnpackVector(v);
}
```

Just for the laughs.

Answer (score 1):

Not really possible. Each function call expression in C++ has a fixed number of arguments. So, there would have to be 100 function call expressions. I.e.

```
switch (myparams.size()) {
  case 0: somefunction(); break;
  case 1: somefunction(myparams[0]); break;
  case 2: somefunction(myparams[0], myparams[1]); break;
  // etc.
```

You may want to use [Boost Preprocessor](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/preprocessor.html) for this.

Comment: I think boost preprocessor would be the solution, looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

If a set of arguments is frequently used together, why not store them in a `struct` and make a wrapper around the existing function that accepts that struct?

Comment: Here the arguments are Id of database objects. So they are dynamic and actually somefunction is a retrieve function which takes one or many id to retrieve as input and an std::vector as last argument for the output object.

Comment: @Dante OK, I'm assuming these functions bind SQL parameters and want to avoid the dynamic SQL that would be necessary for truly variable number of search criteria. I guess, in this case, you can just implement a wrapper that accepts `std::vector`, contains a `switch` on vector's size, and calls one of these database functions accordingly (as MSalters proposed).

Comment: My Mistake, I have a function that accept 99 ids. What we are doing is filling up a vector up to 99, adding empty ids if necessary and then calling somefunction. Somefunction is a generated function by our framework which implement directly the oracle call. We already have an implementation of somefunction with a vector but it does retrieves 5 by 5 (which is not good in our case). Actually the data of the pb is wrong: I just want a prettier way than somefunction(params[0], params[1]...params[98]) to call my function (but now I am thinking that is pointless)

Comment: @Dante Hmm... I know ODP.NET supports [array binding](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html), which could also be used for queries such as "I'll give you a bunch of ID, give me corresponding rows back". Can you use that from C++?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Also, can you use stored procedures? I'm not PL/SQL expert but I believe a stored procedure should be able to accept a truly variable number of input values (through an array or cursor). The stored procedure would then be implemented as a series of queries (one for each ID), but I doubt this would actually be any slower in practice than cramming everything in a single `WHERE id IN (id1, id2, id3...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have somefunction take a pair of iterators; that way you get 0 ... infinity arguments all with the same signature.